# Where is the root of the venv created by PythonVirtualenvOperator located?

Tags: virtualenv, airflow

I have the following structure:

```py
airflow/
     |_ dags/
     |    |_my_project/
     |    |     |_tasks/
     |    |         |_my_task.py
     |    |_utils/
     |_my_dag.py
```

and in `my_dag.py`

```py
from ariflow.operatorss.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator
from my_project.tasks.myt_task import load_data


t1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
python_version = "3.7",
requirements = ["pandas","numpy"],
python_callable = load_data
)
```

Which works fine - sort of. The issue is though that in `load_data` im loading stuff from the `utils` folder i.e

```py
#load_data.py

def load_data():
     from utils.some_utils import some_helper_function
     .
     .
     return 0
```

and when im running the DAG, it fails on `ModuleNotFound: No module named "utils"`. I find it weird, since `utils` and `my_project` is in the same folder, and since I can import `my_project` I assume I can import `utils` aswell.

I note in the log, that `utils` is imported *after* the venv is created, thus placing `os.cwd()` and `os.listdir()` at the top of `load_data` shows, that it is not imported from `dags/` but in the root of its own environment.

So my question is; where is the venv placed and can I add some kind of "PYTHONPATH" argument such that the venv can import `utils`? I know I can hardcode `sys.path+=["/airflow/dags/]` in `load_data` but then I need to do that in all of my tasks-files, which is rather error-prone and clearly does not scale very well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might just be an issue of imports.

Starting from Python 3.3, implicit relative references are allowed no more. That means that the ability to reference a module in the parent directory is not possible and becomes a major limitation.

So in order to reference a module, the directory that contains a module must be present on PYTHONPATH – PYTHONPATH is an environment variable which contains the list of packages that will be loaded by Python upon execution. What is in PYTHONPATH is also present in sys.path as well.

The directory from where a script or module is run is automatically added to PYTHONPATH. You can import any module that lies within this directory, but modules in its parent or sibling directories cannot be imported.

That is, unless you add the path to the desired module to PYTHONPATH or add it to sys.path.

Reference: https://codeolives.com/2020/01/10/python-reference-module-in-parent-directory/

Here is a hacky but a solution for your problem, but I'd highly suggest having your utility folder in the same directory as your tasks.

Comment: Sometimes I can refer to my modules using "." notation, and sometimes I don't. havent figured out why. Adding the path to PYTHONPATH worked though, however it does not answer, which folder the venv created uses as root (thus not accepted as an answer)