# Airflow PythonVirtualenvOperator ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dags'

Tags: python, airflow, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I have a folder structure for my project similar to this:

```
dags/
  git-dagrepo/
    my_module.py
  my_dag.py
```

I am using the PythonVirtualenvOperator and trying to import my_module.py into my_dag.py but it cant seem to find it. I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError. I tried just using the module name, also tried using the entire path but I still get the same error.

Here's my code in the func used by the PythonVirtualenvOperator in my_dag.py

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module("dags.git-dagrepo.my_module")
mod.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same question too. This thread also discusses the issue: [Where is the root of the venv created by PythonVirtualenvOperator located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634040/where-is-the-root-of-the-venv-created-by-pythonvirtualenvoperator-located)

What seems to be happening is that the virtualenv operator creates a completely isolated environment where the dags folder isn't in the PYTHONPATH.
However, I couldn't get the solution in the above thread to work. The only way that worked for me was by hardcoding the path in the dag, essentially like this:

```
def my_task():
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, <path/to/dags/folder>)

    ...

virtualenv_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="virtualenv_python",
    python_callable=my_task,
    requirements=[.....],
    system_site_packages=False,
)
```

This feels very hacky so I'm also curious to see if there's a proper fix.

Comment: Thanks Eishitha. I ended up doing the same thing. Hoping for a more "cleaner" solution.